# Silverlight 4, XAML: How to extend <toolkit:BusyIndicator> to several grid columns?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit, busyindicator

So I have a following XAML code:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="214" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="42" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <toolkit:BusyIndicator IsBusy="False" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
            <!-- ... -->
        </StackPanel>
        <Canvas Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <!-- ... -->
        </Canvas>
    </toolkit:BusyIndicator>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
</Grid>
```

The idea is to have BusyIndicator to cover both cells in the first row and leave second row as is. But XAML editor in Visual Studio underlines `<Canvas>` and says: "The property 'Content' is set more than once."

How to overcome this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting the error about 'Content' being set more than once because a `BusyIndicator` is a `ContentControl` and can only have at most one child.

What you can do instead is put the BusyIndicator inside the grid as siblings of your `StackPanel` and `Canvas`.  To ensure that it appears above the other controls in the top row when it is busy, use the property `Canvas.ZIndex`.  This needs to have a higher Z-index than any controls within your stackpanel and canvas.  (If you're not using Z-indexes in your stackpanel and canvas, `1` will do, as in the example below.)

```
<Grid>
    <!-- ... -->
    <toolkit:BusyIndicator IsBusy="False" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Canvas.ZIndex="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/ >
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
        <!-- ... -->
    </StackPanel>
    <Canvas Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <!-- ... -->
    </Canvas>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
</Grid>
```